# VersionOne Unknown AssetType

Tags: c#, versionone

I'm trying to use the VersionOne API via the [C# APIClient](https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.NET.APIClient), but my meta model is only getting an `Unknown AssetType` error wrapping a 405 exception. What am I doing wrong? Here's a code snippet:

```
VersionOneAPIConnector conn = VersionOneClientFactory.CreateClient(Endpoint.Data);
conn.WithVersionOneUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
IMetaModel meta = new MetaModel(VersionOneClientFactory.CreateClient(Endpoint.Meta));
Services s = new Services(meta, conn);
```

If it helps, here's the `CreateClient` method:

```
public static VersionOneAPIConnector CreateClient(Endpoint e)
{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("https://www#.v1host.com/MyCompany/");
    switch (e)
    {
        case Endpoint.Data: url.Append("rest-1.v1"); break;
        case Endpoint.Localization: url.Append("loc-2.v1"); break;
        case Endpoint.Meta: url.Append("meta.v1"); break;
        case Endpoint.Query: url.Append("query.v1"); break;
    }
    return new VersionOneAPIConnector(
        url.ToString(),
        proxyProvider: new ProxyProvider(
            new Uri("http://proxy.server"),
            "proxy_username",
            "proxy_password"
    ));
}
```

Here's what I see in Visual Studio:

[image: Debugging in Visual Studio]

In this case I use a breakpoint to show you the issues in the Locals window. If I were to actually try to do anything, the MetaException gets thrown.

Comment: Might be helpful to show us where you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fix it:

```
proxyProvider: new ProxyProvider(
    new Uri("https://proxy.server:port"),
    "proxy_username",
    "proxy_password"
)
```

I could've sworn whatever example I was using said to not include port. Apparently that was fallacious. Sorry for the trouble guys, but thanks for trying to help!

---

Also, verified that [mkunzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910328/1680677) is valid too. You need the slashes at the end of the endpoints (e.g. `"meta.v1/"`) or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and ran into the same issue. I was able to make it work by adding a "/" at the end of each endpoint (the meta endpoint in particular). Could you try that?

Comment: I've tried that (and to be thorough I tried it again just now), but I still get the MetaException.

Comment: Just wondering: Did you have a proxy involved when you tried figuring this out? I'm wondering if that is indirectly causing my problems.

Comment: I was not using a proxy since it failed without using one the first time. Looking into that at the moment. Since that error happens when the meta endpoint cannot be resolved properly something going wrong with the proxy is a possibility.

Comment: I just tried with the proxy and it's working properly. What happens if you go to `https://www#.v1host.com/MyCompany/meta.v1/` in your browser? Are you able to see the xml with all the metadata?

Comment: Yes, and I've verified that the Asset Types I see in the exceptions are indeed there.